# Replace image with another image, then replace again after timeout - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to do the following:

onClick, replace image1 with image2, then after 5 seconds, replace image 2 with image 1 again.

Image 1 is replaced with image 2, but my problem is that it doesn't revert back after the timeout.

Here is my code:

```
<img id="loadimg" style="display:none;" src="images/Loader.gif" width="140" height="30" />

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function showLoad(){
    document.getElementById('Generate1').src=document.getElementById('loadimg').src;
    setTimeout(showCode(), 5000);
}

function showCode(){
    document.getElementById('loadimg').src=document.getElementById('Generate1').src;
}

</script>

 <td colspan="3" rowspan="3"><img src="images/BUTTON.gif" alt="" name="Generate1" width="168" height="40" id="Generate1" onClick="showLoad()"></td>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because old images is being "run-over" by new one. You could do something like this:

```
var pathToGenerateImg = "..."; // path to generate
var pathToLoadImg = "..."; // path to load img

function showLoad(){
    document.getElementById('Generate1').src = pathToLoadImg;
    setTimeout(showCode, 5000);
}

function showCode(){
    document.getElementById('Generate1').src = pathToGenerateImg ;
}
```

In this case you only need single `<IMG>` container (with `id="Generate1"`) as all paths are stored in variables.

Answer (score 1):

You have to address the same image with id `Generate1` and store initial image `src` in temp value (e.g. `var image`):

```
var image = document.getElementById('Generate1').src;

function showLoad(){
    document.getElementById('Generate1').src = document.getElementById('loadimg').src;
    setTimeout(showCode, 5000);
}

function showCode(){
    document.getElementById('Generate1').src = image;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to run `showCode` and pass the result to `setTimeout`, you want to pass the function itself as an argument to `setTimeout` so it can be called back:

```
setTimeout(showCode, 5000);
```

Also, when you assign `document.getElementById('loadimg').src` to `document.getElementById('Generate1').src`, doing the reverse won't change anything. You need to keep the original in a variable. You may as well keep your elements in variables, too:

```
var Generate1 = document.getElementById('Generate1');
var loadimg = document.getElementById('loadimg');
var originalSrc = Generate1.src;

function showLoad() {
    Generate1.src = loadimg.src;
    setTimeout(showCode, 5000);
}

function showCode() {
    loadimg.src = originalSrc;
}
```